# Will a router's DHCP/ARP table show a network switch?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, switch, pfsense

My network setup:

wan > pfsense router > switch > unifi AP

Well I just got the switch. Brand new. I'm trying to set it up, but it's showing two IP addresses. The switch config utility says "IP address: 10.12.1.128" and then the next column says "Located on IP network: 10.12.1.131"

Does located on IP network mean the default gateway? Because my default gateway is 10.12.1.1.

So I tried to find my switch on pfsense to see what the actual IP was, but pfsense doesnt even list my switch on the arp or dhcp table. I have internet connectivity though so that means it established a link.

Do switches just not show up on an arp table? 
Whats the difference between the two IP addresses?

Edit: my desktop is plugged into the switch. My desktops IP is 10.12.1.131. Now I just need to know why the switch wont show on my router

Comment: What make and model is the switch? What “switch config utility” are you using? How would it help if the switch were to appear on pfSense?

Comment: tplink tl-sg105e. Tp link provides an installation cd to manage the switch.  I like to assign my devices static IP addresses. If my router or switch turns off I dont want it to be assigned a new IP address every single time. But I can't assign a static IP address because pfsense doesnt even show its leasing an IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, you want to make a DHCP reservation. The MAC address should be indicated somewhere on the device. It should also show up in the configuration utility.

In the [configuration utility’s manual](http://www.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/Easy_Smart_Configuration_Utility_UG.pdf), on page 16, it says:

> DHCP Setting: Enable or disable the DHCP function. If DHCP setting is enabled, the switch will obtain the IP address, subnet Mask and default gateway from the DHCP Server automatically; otherwise, these three items should be configured manually. **By default, it is disabled.**

(Emphasis mine)

So by default, the switch is using some undefined method to acquire an IP address. You must set it to use DHCP.

Comment: Ohh. I thought that meant make the switch act as a DHCP server and hand out IP addresses to everything that goes through it.

Comment: No, it’s unlikely you’d find a feature like that in any managed switch. Well, perhaps on some semi-enterprise-y units.